# Alarm manager won't work on app closed

Tags: android, alarmmanager

I'm trying to set events with `AlarmManager`, but I'm getting notifications only when the app is opened. I tried with `set`, `setExact` and `setExactAndAllowWhileIdle` but with no luck : when i close the app, even when I don't turn off the screen, I won't get notified.

**Adding notification**

```
    public void addNotification(Task task) {

    Intent intent = new Intent(context, NotificationPublisher.class);
    intent.putExtra("NOTIFICATION",getNotification(task));
    intent.putExtra("TASK_ID",(int)task.getTaskId());
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);


    if(DateUtility.isTimePast(new Time(task.getNotificationTime()))) // if missed, notify now
        mAlarmManager.setExactAndAllowWhileIdle(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, today.getTime()+3000, pendingIntent);
    else
        mAlarmManager.setExactAndAllowWhileIdle(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, task.getNotificationTime(), pendingIntent);
}
```

**Notification publisher** , called by the alarm manager

```
public class NotificationPublisher extends BroadcastReceiver {
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager)context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    Notification notification = intent.getParcelableExtra("NOTIFICATION");
    int id = intent.getIntExtra("TASK_ID", 0);
    if(notification!=null&&id!=0)
        notificationManager.notify(id, notification);

    }
}
```

My custom classes or methods aren't involved, since I'm getting notified correctly when my app isn't closed.

I set my alarms again on boot with `RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED` too, which notifies me of late notifications only (if my phone was turned off during an event, I will be notified at next boot). So alarms are set correctly, but a few seconds later it dies. Thanks for your help!